# C Socket programming sending data from a large text file line by line to a server

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am trying to send contents from a big text file from a client to a server line by line, but it always caps out at line **84**, even though there are **10000** total lines read from files. It works fine with a smaller file, so I believe the problem lies somewhere in the server receiving buffer, because all the lines are read in the client just fine.

I am a total newbie to C and TCP socket programming, so any insight would be greatly appreciated.

My code so far:
**Client**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define PORT "20000"
#define HOST "::1"

int main()
{
  struct addrinfo hints, *res, *result;
  int sockfd;
  char *line = NULL;
  size_t len = 0;
  ssize_t readLine;
  int number;
  FILE *filePointer;
  int valread;

  memset (&hints, 0, sizeof (hints));
  hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
  hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  hints.ai_flags |= AI_PASSIVE;

  int errcode = getaddrinfo (HOST, PORT, &hints, &result);
  if (errcode != 0){
    perror ("Nepavyko gauti adreso");
    return -1;
  }
  res = result;
  while (res){
    sockfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if (!(sockfd < 0))
    break;
    res = res->ai_next;
  }
  if (connect(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
        perror("Prisijungimas nepavyko");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  filePointer = fopen("dataBIG.txt", "r");
  if (filePointer == NULL) { 
    printf("Nepavyko atidaryti data.txt") ; 
  } 
  else {  
    readLine = getline(&line, &len, filePointer)-1;
    sscanf(line, "%d", &number);
    send(sockfd, line, sizeof(line), 0);
    valread = recv(sockfd, line, sizeof(line), 0);
    for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
        readLine = getline(&line, &len, filePointer)-1;
        printf("%d\n", i);
        if(readLine != 0){
            send(sockfd, line, sizeof(line), 0);
        }
        valread = recv(sockfd, line, sizeof(line), 0);
    }
      fclose(filePointer); 
  }
  freeaddrinfo(result);
  return 0;
}
```

**Server**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define PORT1 "20000"
#define HOST "::1"

int main()
{
 struct addrinfo hints, *res, *result;
 int errcode;
 char str[300];
 void *ptr;
 int sockfd, new_socket, valread;
 int number;
 char *message = "ALL GOOD";

 memset (&hints, 0, sizeof (hints));
 hints.ai_family = PF_UNSPEC;
 hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
 hints.ai_flags |= AI_PASSIVE;

 errcode = getaddrinfo (HOST, PORT1, &hints, &result);
 if (errcode != 0){
    perror ("Nepavyko gauti adreso");
    return -1;
 }
 res = result;
 while (res){
    sockfd = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);
    if (!(sockfd < 0))
    break;
    res = res->ai_next;
 }

 if (bind(sockfd, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) < 0) {
    perror("Bindas neivyko");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 if (listen(sockfd, 3) < 0){
    perror("Listen klaida");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
 int addrlen = sizeof(res);
 if ((new_socket = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&res, (socklen_t*)&addrlen)) < 0) {
    perror("Accept klaida");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 valread = recv(new_socket, str, sizeof(str), 0);
 sscanf(str, "%d", &number);
 send(new_socket, message, sizeof(message), 0);
 for(int i = 0; i < number; i++){
    valread1 = recv(new_socket, str, sizeof(str), 0);
    int l = strlen(str);
    int j = 0, count = 0;
    for(j; j < l; j++){
        if ('a' == str[j] || 'A' == str[j])
            count++;
    }
    printf("%d letter A count = %d\n", i+1, count);
    sprintf(str, "%d", count);
    send(new_socket, message, sizeof(message), 0);
 }
 freeaddrinfo(result);
 return 0;
}
```

**Data file**

```
10000
Hi
Car
Alex
...
```

Comment: *always caps out*. Please be precise. What does that mean exactly? It crashes? One of the function calls fails? The client doesn't send enough? The server doesn't receive what was sent? etc. These are all things you should have observed or be able to find out with basic debugging.

Comment: `send(sockfd, line, sizeof(line), 0);` is your first big problem. What do you think `sizeof(line)` is?

Comment: Another error you have is that you assume every `recv` will receive exactly the requested number of bytes. That is not the case with streaming protocols like TCP. You need to check the return value of each `recv` call to know exactly how much was received. This is quite a common misunderstanding.

Comment: @kaylum the server client doesnt receive enough lines sent it always crashes about line 84. But until that line it works fine.

Comment: Why send lines at all? Why not just copy the bytes? and why all the replies? You don't need all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it's a file you should first use:

```
FILE *File = fopen("Data.txt", "rb");
fseek(File, 0, SEEK_END);
i = ftell(File);
fseek(File, 0, SEEK_SET);
u_int8_t *Memory4Data = (u_int8_t*) malloc (i);
fread(Memory4Data, i, 1, File);
```

then you shouldn't send them all of them at once:

```
// allocate 4 byte memory for Memory2Send
Remained_Data = i;
j = 0
while (Remained_Data > 0){
      if(Remained_Data > 4){
          memcpy(Memory2Send, Memory4Data + j, 4;
          send(Sock, Memory2Send, 4, 0);
          j = j + 4;
          Remained_Data = Remained_Data - 4;
      }
      else if(Remained_Data < 4){
          memcpy(Memory2Send, Memory4Data + j, 4;
          send(Sock, Memory2Send, Remained_Data, 0);
          Remained_Data = 0;
      }
```

try to send 4 bytes every round.
you'll get all the data

and for server-side you need to receive 4 bytes every round.

```
j = 1;
z = 0;
while (j != 0) {
    bzero(Memory4Recv,4);
    recv(Sock, Memory4Recv, 4, 0);
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        Recv_Data[z] = Memory4Recv[i];
        if (Recv_Data[z] == 0x00){
            j = 0;
            break;
            }
        z++;
        }
    }
```

put a null byte at the end of the file;

you can do it by :

```
fread(Memory4Data, i + 1, 1, File);
```

try to make your file size a multiply of 4 so won't receive any error on receiving the data

if you want to manage your communication better, you can start with creating your own protocol